# Implementing merge sort iteratively

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to implement merge sort in order to get a better understanding of how it works.  In the following code I am attempting to sort an array of numbers.  The code I currently have is buggy and runs in an infinite loop.  I'm trying to solve this non-recursively for now:

```
function mergeSort(arr) {

  var mid = Math.floor(arr.length/2);
  var left = arr.slice(0, mid);
  var right = arr.slice(mid, arr.length);

  if (arr.length === 1) {return arr};

  var sorted = [];

  var i = 0;

  while (left.length || right.length) {
   if (left.length && right.length) {
     if (left[0] < right[0]) {
       sorted.push(left.shift())
     } else {
       sorted.push(right.shift())
     }
   } else if (left) {
     sorted.push(left.shift())
   } else {
     sorted.push(right.shift())
   }
   i++;
  }

  return sorted;
}
```

So if I have an array `var nums = [1, 4, 10, 2, 9, 3];` calling `mergeSort(nums)` should return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10]`.

Comment: Where do you define `merge`?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How are we supposed to help when you haven't provided any input or expected results?

Comment: Apologies.  I have now provided input and expected results.  Further, I am expecting this function to only work on an array of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've written code that splits an array in two and merges the halves. This doesn't result in a sorted array because the two halves are not sorted. Mergesort works by sorting the two halves, then merging them.

There are many ways to implement mergesort iteratively. Let me offer one. Start by merging subarrays of size 1. You know that an array of size 1 is already sorted, so it's safe to merge two consecutive subarrays of size 1. If you do this to all consecutive pairs of subarrays of size 1 in the original array, you end up with an array consisting of consecutive sorted subarrays of size 2.

Do you see where this is going? Now you can merge every two consecutive subarrays of size 2. You end up with an array of consecutive sorted subarrays of size 4. Keep on repeating this procedure until the whole array is sorted.

The following snippet implements this approach.

```js
function mergeSort(arr) {
  var sorted = arr.slice(),
      n = sorted.length,
      buffer = new Array(n);

  for (var size = 1; size < n; size *= 2) {
    for (var leftStart = 0; leftStart < n; leftStart += 2*size) {
      var left = leftStart,
          right = Math.min(left + size, n),
          leftLimit = right,
          rightLimit = Math.min(right + size, n),
          i = left;
      while (left < leftLimit && right < rightLimit) {
        if (sorted[left] <= sorted[right]) {
          buffer[i++] = sorted[left++];
        } else {
          buffer[i++] = sorted[right++];
        }
      }
      while (left < leftLimit) {
        buffer[i++] = sorted[left++];
      }
      while (right < rightLimit) {
        buffer[i++] = sorted[right++];
      }
    }
    var temp = sorted,
        sorted = buffer,
        buffer = temp;
  }

  return sorted;
}

function print(s) {
  document.write(s + '<br />');
}

var data = [1, 4, 10, 2, 9, 3];
print('input: ' + data.join(', '));
print('output: ' + mergeSort(data).join(', '));
```

Comment: Don't these nested loops result in a crazy time complexity?

Comment: Note that the index of the outer loop doubles on each iteration, so the loop runs O(log n) times. The inner loop is a linear scan. Thus, the overall time complexity is O(n log n).

Comment: At the end of the inner loop, why swap sorted with buffer, isn't buffer just going to be overwritten. sorted = buffer; buffer = [] does seem to work fine. I don't get why we need to save previous sorted's values when we don't reuse them