# Bottom Up Merge Sort Javascript Implementation

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, in-place, sub-array

I am having trouble understanding how to translate the code from:
[Algorithmist](https://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_merge_sort)

into javascript. Ive added how i understand the code below. My code returns the original array every time. I think this is because i still am not separating the array into "blocks" properly.

```js
function merge(list,arr1,arr2,blockSize){
 var i=0, j=0, k=0,n=list.length;
 while (i < blockSize && j < n){
  if(list[i]<arr1[i]){
  arr2[k++]=list[i++];
 }
 else{
  arr2[k++]=arr1[i++];
 }
 }
 while(i<blockSize){
  arr2[k++]=list[i++];
 }
 while(j<n){
  arr2[k++]=arr1[j++]
 }
}
function mergeSort(list){
 var j,k,blockSize,w,
 n=list.length;
 for(blockSize=1;blockSize<n;blockSize*=2);
 if(blockSize!=n){
  return list;
 }
 else{
  w= new Array(n);
  for(k=1;k<n;k*=2){
   for(j=0; j<(n-k); j+=2*k){
    merge(list+j,list+j+k,w+k,k);
   }
   for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    list[j]=w[j];
   }
  }return list;
 }
}
const list = [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
console.log("Merge Sort: :");
console.log(mergeSort(list));
console.log("\n");
```

Comment: It will be better if you look at this code instead: https://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort.c.

Comment: What would be the JavaScript calloc?

Comment: Is the code found in the answer here:( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041092/implementing-merge-sort-iteratively ) in place? if not, why not?

Comment: [Calloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) allocates memory for an array of `N` elements, you can do `new Array(N)` in javascript. However, it will be better to understand the idea and implement your own procedure, not a direct translation.

Comment: I really do understand the idea of non-dynamic memory allocation, i just am not familiar enough with the language to implement it very easily and i am struggling.