# Iterative approach of Merge Sort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement merge sort iteratively but in javascript. I tried searching on the internet as well but they only have in C, Python, and java. The array my function is giving is not sorted. I tried different things but can't figure out the error. Can someone point out please what I am doing wrong?

```
function mergeSortIterative(arr){
    let sorted=[...arr];//copying the array so that original remains unchanged.
    let n=sorted.length;
    let currSize;
    let leftStart;
    for(currSize=1;currSize<=n-1;currSize=2*currSize){
        for(leftStart=0;leftStart<n-1;leftStart+=2*currSize){
            let mid=Math.min(leftStart+currSize-1,n-1);
            let rightEnd=Math.min(leftStart+2*currSize-1,n-1);
            // let left=sorted.slice(leftStart,mid);
            // let right=sorted.slice(mid,rightEnd);
            // sorted=mergeIterative(sorted,left,right);
            mergeIterative(sorted,leftStart,mid,rightEnd);
        }
    }
    return sorted;
}

function mergeIterative(sorted,leftStart,mid,rightEnd){
    let left=sorted.slice(leftStart,mid);
    let right=sorted.slice(mid,rightEnd);
    let leftIndex=0,rightIndex=0,k=leftStart;
    while(leftIndex<left.length && rightIndex<right.length){
        //picking the lesser one 
        if(left[leftIndex]<=right[rightIndex]){
            sorted[k]=left[leftIndex];
            leftIndex++;
            k++;
        }
        else{
            sorted[k]=right[rightIndex];
            rightIndex++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while(leftIndex<left.length && k<sorted.length){
        sorted[k]=left[leftIndex];
        leftIndex++;
        k++;
    }
    while(rightIndex<right.length && k<sorted.length){
        sorted[k]=right[rightIndex];
        rightIndex++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: so you are saying merge sort in js does not exist on the web?

Comment: No. I meant the iterative approach and its not that it does not exist, its hard to find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your code is in an inconsistent definition of what `mid` and `rightEnd` mean.

From the following code, we learn that those indexes point to the entry *after* the preceding subarray:

```
let left = sorted.slice(leftStart, mid);
let right = sorted.slice(mid, rightEnd);
```

But when looking at the assignments:

```
let mid = Math.min(leftStart + currSize - 1, n - 1); 
let rightEnd = Math.min(leftStart + 2 * currSize - 1, n - 1);
```

... we see that they point to the final element of the preceding sub array.

You can correct this in two ways, but since the way `slice` interprets its arguments is the "standard" way, I would suggest to make the correction in the assignments, removing all those `- 1`, as follows:

```
let mid = Math.min(leftStart + currSize, n); 
let rightEnd = Math.min(leftStart + 2 * currSize, n);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I saw its implementation in Java and they had -1 there. Can you please explain a bit more about that?

Comment: Like I wrote, there are two ways to correct it. Probably the Java version had the slices implemented in a way that included the end-indexes in the slice. So it went with a different semantic for `mid` and `rightEnd`.

Answer (score 1):

Pranav: I've quoted below an iterative merge sort algorithm provided by [Michael Laszlo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4275347/michael-laszlo) to a similar question asked before: [Implementing merge sort iteratively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041092/implementing-merge-sort-iteratively)

> ```js
> function mergeSort(arr) {
>   var sorted = arr.slice(),
>       n = sorted.length,
>       buffer = new Array(n);
>
>   for (var size = 1; size < n; size *= 2) {
>     for (var leftStart = 0; leftStart < n; leftStart += 2*size) {
>       var left = leftStart,
>           right = Math.min(left + size, n),
>           leftLimit = right,
>           rightLimit = Math.min(right + size, n),
>           i = left;
>       while (left < leftLimit && right < rightLimit) {
>         if (sorted[left] <= sorted[right]) {
>           buffer[i++] = sorted[left++];
>         } else {
>           buffer[i++] = sorted[right++];
>         }
>       }
>       while (left < leftLimit) {
>         buffer[i++] = sorted[left++];
>       }
>       while (right < rightLimit) {
>         buffer[i++] = sorted[right++];
>       }
>     }
>     var temp = sorted,
>         sorted = buffer,
>         buffer = temp;
>   }
>
>   return sorted;
> }
>
> function print(s) {
>   document.write(s + '<br />');
> }
>
> var data = [1, 4, 10, 2, 9, 3];
> print('input: ' + data.join(', '));
> print('output: ' + mergeSort(data).join(', '));
> ```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have seen that before. But, they have done it in function only so I thought I will look at that after finding problems in my code.